# Comparing JSON Arrays with MySQL 8

Tags: json, mysql-8.0

I have a Table in the form of:

| Id (int) | Tags (JSON) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [1, 2, 3] |
| 2 | [1, 4, 5] |
| 3 | [1, 3] |

I would like to construct a `SELECT` statement where I can compare the Array stored in the column *Tags* with another Array. For Example, for the search-Array [1, 3] I would expect the query to return rows 1 and 3, but not row 2.

Is there an easy and/or nifty way (preferable without having to use JSON_TABLE) to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Btw.: I decided to stop using JSON in this case and keep normalized tables instead, my requirement seems to be a real hassle to implement especially for large lists. If only JSON_OVERLAPS would not just return true/null, but the actual number of overlaps - that would be ideal to implement my requirement. Anyway ... still happy for answers and useful recommendations.